# Three dimensional autoencoder has low MSE loss but gives noisy reconstruction image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, deep-learning, pytorch

I am re-constructing spatio-temporal cuboids of 3-dimensional size with width and height equal to 32 and depth equal to 20. I am using Conv3d layers in my autoencoder architecture.

So my input shape is 32x32x20, which I am reducing to size 2048, and then reconstructing it back to 32x32x20.

The MSE loss of the model has nice convergence even though the reconstruction is just noise.

My encoder architecture:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
            Conv3d-1       [-1, 64, 20, 32, 32]           5,248
         AvgPool3d-2       [-1, 64, 10, 16, 16]               0
            Conv3d-3      [-1, 128, 10, 16, 16]         221,312
         AvgPool3d-4         [-1, 128, 5, 8, 8]               0
            Conv3d-5         [-1, 256, 5, 8, 8]         884,992
         AvgPool3d-6         [-1, 256, 2, 4, 4]               0
            Conv3d-7         [-1, 512, 2, 4, 4]       3,539,456
         AvgPool3d-8         [-1, 512, 1, 2, 2]               0
```

My decoder architecture:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
       Interpolate-1         [-1, 512, 2, 4, 4]               0
            Conv3d-2         [-1, 256, 4, 4, 4]       3,539,200
       Interpolate-3         [-1, 256, 8, 8, 8]               0
            Conv3d-4        [-1, 128, 10, 8, 8]         884,864
       Interpolate-5      [-1, 128, 20, 16, 16]               0
            Conv3d-6       [-1, 64, 20, 16, 16]         221,248
       Interpolate-7       [-1, 64, 40, 32, 32]               0
            Conv3d-8        [-1, 3, 40, 32, 32]           5,187
            Conv3d-9        [-1, 3, 20, 32, 32]             246
```

My reconstruction code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
# recon_batch is the last batch of the autoencoder output.
# recon_batch has shape (batch_size, 3, 20, 32, 32)
recon_batch = recon_batch.permute(0, 2, 3, 4, 1) # new shape = (batch_size, 20, 32, 32, 3)
recon_batch = recon_batch.detach().cpu()
recon_batch_numpy = recon_batch.detach().cpu().numpy()
for k in range(3):  # K=3 because I want to display 3 frames
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4., 4.))
    grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,  
                      nrows_ncols=(4, 4),  
                      axes_pad=0.1,  
                      )
    images = [recon_batch_numpy[i][k] for i in range(16)]  # 16 because Original Image is of size (128x128), when I make 32x32 patches, 16 sub frames are formed
    for ax, im in zip(grid, images):
        ax.imshow((rgb2gray(im) * 255).astype(np.uint8), cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
    name = str(num_epochs) + 'th_figure_' + str(k)
    plt.savefig(name)
```

Original input image(actual cuboids of size 32x32x20, the image is reconstructed by taking the first frame for depth 0 of each such cuboid):

[image: original input image]

The reconstructed output image:

[image: reconstructed image]

If needed, I can also add a loss plot, the loss starts around 10,000 and converges around 200.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your loss term or training process looks like, but you may want to consider a couple of things:

1. training for more epochs since 200 may be a relatively large MSE (and you may be stuck in a local minima for which case a higher gradient or different optimizer/optimizer hyper-parameters may help)
2. changing you loss term by using a different loss or by adding additional terms to the loss; such as, KL-divergence

Comment: Thanks for answering, David. 1) I have to train the neural net for a very large number of epochs for slight drop in the loss, once it has reached around 200. So, the neural net has converged around 200 loss. I am using Adam optimizer, if I am correct Adam optimizer in PyTorch uses a learning rate scheduler. 2) By adding a different loss, do you mean to regularize the model? I haven't tried to regularize my model, since my plan is to initially overfit it, to see the reconstruction. Since it is unable to re-create the input, I am not sure if regularizing would help.

Comment: What does your loss consist of? Also, is the reconstruction completing another task while reconstructing the image?

1) yes Adam does automatically change the lr, and has momentum and parameters affecting momentum. The initial setting can still affect outcome of the training even after many epochs.

2) by changing the loss I mean just changing the criterion in general. Like say using your f(x) loss function and changing it to lambda_1f(x) + lambda_2g(x) where the lambdas are weighting parameters and the g(x) is another loss term like l2 or perceptual loss if that fits your objective and data